# Creating Laravel repositories and binding as service providers

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, repository-pattern

I have a Symfony and Spring background, this is my first project with Laravel and as far as I understood Laravel doesn't have a build-in support for repositories. I found several tutorials; some of them try to offer architecture like Spring or Symfony.

As an example this blog [suggests an folder structure](https://dev.to/asperbrothers/laravel-repository-pattern-how-to-use-why-it-matters-1g9d) like this:

```
---- Repository
------ Eloquent
-------- UserRepository.php // extends BaseRepository
-------- BaseRepository.php // implements EloquentRepositoryInterface
------ UserRepositoryInterface.php
------ EloquentRepositoryInterface.php
```

which is not bad. The point I'm confused is, the author suggests to bind these repositories as service providers and access them in controller as providers.

```
class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{  
    public function register() 
    { 
        $this->app->bind(EloquentRepositoryInterface::class, BaseRepository::class);
        $this->app->bind(UserRepositoryInterface::class, UserRepository::class);
    }
}
```

Than I decided to find a library in Github which focuses on creating an Eloquent Repository, which directly consumes User repository in controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        return $userRepository->get();
        ...
```

From architectural perspective, **do we need to bind repositories as providers**? (Let's think the fact that AWS or Elastic Search may join the project and repositories may vary for a single model)

And most importantly why doesn't Laravel have a built-in repository pattern support?
Thank you

Comment: Laravel doesn't have a built-in repository pattern because it's not a use case by default

Comment: Laravel doesn't need it, Eloquent would need it just like Doctrine uses it but because Eloquent's database operations are in the model, like most ActiveRecord ORMs, it doesn't really *need* the repository pattern. I wouldn't create a separate interface though, that's what .NET does it's not really useful to have an interface per class when it's only going to be used on one class. Just bind to the repository class, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why doesn't Laravel have a built-in repository pattern

Because there is no consensus on how they should be used if used at all.

For example, I use Repositories as an intermediary between laravel models and laravel controllers that needs the model instance to be instantiated and I never inject them into controllers but instantiate them manually when needed.

> do we need to bind repositories as providers ?

As said above, there is no consensus so **NO**.

Depends on how you design your repositories, you can instantiate them manually, inject them into controller's instantiation (in the `__contruct(UserRepository $userRepository)`) as you can see in laravel from scratch tutorial from laracast or use them as service providers.

Answer (score 1):

**From [Laravel Repository Pattern – How to use & why it matters](https://dev.to/asperbrothers/laravel-repository-pattern-how-to-use-why-it-matters-1g9d)**

> The last step is to register this service provider in our config/app.php. Open this file and add to providers our provider App\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class
>
> Now our application knows what class it should use when we type an
>   objects by its interfaces.

This is why you need to bind your interfaces like that:

```
/** 
* Register services. 
* 
* @return void  
*/ 
public function register() 
{ 
   $this->app->bind(EloquentRepositoryInterface::class, BaseRepository::class);
   $this->app->bind(UserRepositoryInterface::class, UserRepository::class);
}
```

In order to let Laravel knows about what to instantiate when you do in your controller:

```
private $userRepository;

public function __construct(UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository)
{
   $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}
```

**[EDIT 1]**

Also there is a great article from the Laravel documentation for **Dependency Injection**: **[laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)**